# How is this IOException error not stopped by my try with resources block in this code?

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm getting an error message for an unreported IOException (must be caught or declared to be thrown) from the call to the checkArguments() method in the start() method. I've tried everything I can think of to fix this. The checkArguments() method calls another method, copyFiles(), that opens a BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutPut stream. Those are enclosed in a try with resources and every method in the call chain declares throws IOException. Also, I noticed that if I take the "throws IOException" out of the start method, it doesn't change the error, but if I take it out of the next method in the chain, checkArguments(), it does change the error. It's the same error, but it now only cites it for the call to copyFiles() from checkArguments(). I just can't figure out what that means or how I need to set up the try with resources differently to get rid of this error. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
import java.io.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class Chapter17 extends Application {
   @Override // Override the start method in Application
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
      // Create borderpane
      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
      // String to hold instructions
      String instructions = "If the base file is named temp.txt with three pieces," +
     " temp.txt.1, temp.txt.2, and temp.txt.3 are combined into temp.txt.";
      // Add instructions string to label and set in top of border pane
      pane.setTop(new Label(instructions));   
      // Create gridPane to hold text fields and labels in center of border pane
      GridPane grid = new GridPane();
      grid.setHgap(5);
      grid.setVgap(5);

      // Create text fields for the file name and number of files
      TextField tf1 = new TextField();
      TextField tf2 = new TextField();      

      //Add text fields and labels to grid pane
      grid.add(new Label("Enter a file:"), 0, 0);
      grid.add(tf1, 1, 0);
      grid.add(new Label("Specify the number of files:"), 1, 0);
      grid.add(tf2, 1, 1);

      // Add Grid Pane to center of Border Pane
      pane.setCenter(grid);

      // Create start button
      Button btOk = new Button("Start");

      // Add button to bottom of Border Pane
      pane.setBottom(btOk);

      // Create handler for start button
      btOk.setOnAction(e -> {
         int fileCount = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
         String[] arguments = new String[fileCount];
         String file = new String(tf1.getText());
         for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
            arguments[i] = (tf1.getText() + "." + i);

         checkArguments(arguments, file);
      });



      Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250, 200);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.setTitle("Chapter 17");
      primaryStage.show();       
   }

   public static void checkArguments(String[] arguments, String file)

       throws IOException {

      // Create an array of File objects to hold source files
      File[] sourceFiles = new File[arguments.length];

      // Check to make sure files exist, create array of File objects
      for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
         sourceFiles[i] = checkIfFileExists(arguments[i]);

      // Check if target file already exists
      File targetFile = new File(file);
      if (targetFile.exists()) {
         System.out.println("Target file " + (arguments.length) + " already exists");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      // Create input streams, output streams, copy file to target file
      for (int i = 0; i < (arguments.length); i++)
         copyFiles(sourceFiles[i], targetFile);
   }

   /** Method to create BufferedInputStream for every source file and copy it to the target*/
      public static void copyFiles(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws                         IOException {
      try (
      // Create input stream
      BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
         new FileInputStream(sourceFile));

      // Create output stream
      RandomAccessFile output = new RandomAccessFile(
         targetFile, "rw");
      ) {

       // Attempt to copy input form source file to target file
       int r = 0;
       output.seek(output.length());
       while ((r = input.read()) != -1)
          output.write((byte)r);
       }
   }

   /** Method to see if file exists */
   public static File checkIfFileExists(String file) {
      File sourceFile = new File(file);
      if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
         System.out.println("File " + file + " does not exist");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      return sourceFile;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Application.launch(args);
   }
}
```

Comment: because you do not have a `catch` block

Comment: Is that even a valid `try` block?

Comment: My book never uses a catch block for any of the binary input/output examples, just the try-with-resources. I was under the impression this was simply to close the input/output streams. Do I just need a catch block after my try-with-resources? Thanks so much for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Use a try-catch block

```
try {
    /* 
       do things 
       initialize a stream, create a file, etc
       try to close file
     */
} catch(IOException e) {
    /* 
       something bad happened 
       close file stream
     */
}
```

You can replace the `IOException` with the more generic `Exception`. Since you may be working with multiple possible exceptions, `e.getMessage()` will tell you what the exception was.

Answer (score 0):

Try-with-resources doesn't protect you against exceptions; it only makes sure the resource is properly opened and closed even in case of exceptions.  You need to catch the IOException in the try-with-resources block and deal with it.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, does that work like this? try (open/close stream) {perform operations on stream} catch (IOException e) {code to process exception} Sorry to ask such a basic question, but I'm having a hard time finding an example of a try/catch combined with try-with-resources.

Comment: @JimboSakahana Yep.  Just add the normal `catch` block after the close of the `try` brace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Have added a catch block to your code

```
/** Method to create BufferedInputStream for every source file and copy it to the target*/
          public static void copyFiles(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws                         IOException {
          try (
          // Create input stream
          BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
             new FileInputStream(sourceFile));

          // Create output stream
          RandomAccessFile output = new RandomAccessFile(
             targetFile, "rw");
          ) {

           // Attempt to copy input form source file to target file
           int r = 0;
           output.seek(output.length());
           while ((r = input.read()) != -1)
              output.write((byte)r);
           }
         catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("YOUR custom message :example-File Not Found!Please check ....." );

                        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the function call copyFiles inside a try block with catch IOException. As Louis said try with resources only make sure the resources specified is properly closed to avoid memory leak

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much you saved my life!